# how can i write a file into an array based on the first part of the name and sort it by that?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, merge, getfiles

The files are named as follows: 5000023_abc_2000045.pdf, 5000023_def_2000045.pdf.

All files are in the same directory.

I want to write all these files sorted into an array and then put them to a 3rd party program to merge them.
It is about 60000 files.

I tried with getfiles, but that didn't work. sorry, i'm a total beginner.

many thanks in advance

Heres my Code

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using bin_vMergePdfNeu.Properties;

namespace System.Configuration
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "bin_vMergePDF";

            // Ordner aus dem die PDF gezogen werden
            string altDirIn = Settings.Default.AlternativeInputDir;
            // Ordner in dem die zusammengeführte PDF abgelegt werden soll
            string altDirOut = Settings.Default.AlternativeOutputDir;

         ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //var paths = new Collections.Generic.List<string>();
        //paths.Add(altDirIn);
        //var cmd = String.Join(" ", altDirIn) + " cat output " + altDirOut;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        string[] rchg = Directory.GetFiles(altDirIn, "*.pdf".Split('_')[0]);

        string cmd = string.Join(" ", rchg) + " cat output " + altDirOut;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "pdftk.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.Start();

        Console.WriteLine(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();

        p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I tried with getfiles, but that didn't work."*. Then you did it wrong. If we can't see what you did, we can't see what's wrong with it. ALWAYS post the relevant code.

Comment: You just want to get the file names or the content as well. What must you pass to the third party app?

Comment: "By the first part of the name"?. I don't get that, any alphabetical sorting would do that anyway. Do you need numerical sorting?

Comment: @John you are right.
have now added my code to the question

Comment: @Jonathan Willcock The complete pdf file. And sorry, I had made a mistake. I meant put and not pass.

Comment: @Palle Due Yes, i want to sort numerically. the first part of the filename before the first _

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to sort the file names the way File Explorer does, rather than straight alphabetically. In that case, you should use the same Windows API function that File Explorer uses. Read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887615-Sorting-AlphaNumeric-Strings-Logically-as-Windows-File-Explorer-Does) to learn how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the job:

```cs
var folder = new DirectoryInfo(altDirIn);
var files = folder.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf").OrderBy(fi => Convert.ToInt32(fi.Name.Split('_')[0]));
var cmd = $"{string.Join(" ", files.Select(fi => fi.FullName))} cat output {altDirOut}";
```

That assumes that every file starts with a number and an underscore.

It's also worth noting that, if you want to sort file names the same way File Explorer does, you can use the same Windows API that File Explorer uses. You can create a comparer that incorporates that API:

```cs
public class LogicalStringComparer : IComparer, IComparer<string>
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);
 
    int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return Compare((string) x, (string) y);
    }
 
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }
}
```

You can then use that class to sort your file paths:

```cs
var filePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(altDirIn, "*.pdf").OrderBy(s => s, new LogicalStringComparer());
var cmd = $"{string.Join(" ", filePaths)} cat output {altDirOut}";
```

It's also worth noting that that code, which is based on what you wrote yourself, is probably going to fail if the folder path or any file name has a space in it. You could quote each path to handle that:

```cs
var cmd = $"""{string.Join(""" """, filePaths)}"" cat output {altDirOut}";
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer/explanation. this has helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that you want to *query* files within directory, and you are going to do

1. Obtain (enumerate) all `*.pdf` files within directory
2. Check if file name matches `number_name` pattern
3. Obtain `number` part to be sorted by it
4. Since `number` is in fact string of arbitrary length, we can't convert it to int; so we sort first by length and the for value
5. Get rid of `number` part; we want to get `file` only
6. Materialize results as an array

**Code:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string[] rchg = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(altDirIn, "*.pdf")
  .Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file))
  .Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(file, "^[0-9]+_"))
  .Select(file => (file : file, number : file.Substring(0, file.IndexOf('_'))))
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.number.TrimStart('0').Length)
  .ThenBy(pair => pair.number)
  .Select(pair => pair.file)
  .ToArray();
```

Then be careful: if you have `60000` files, the array can well be *huge* and hardly you pass it via *command line*. You can try saving the results into a file and pass its name to the exe

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
But now I get the following error message. Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   2000019
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   2000019
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   2000020
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   2000020
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   2000021
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file:2000021
Errors encountered.No output created.
Done.  Input errors,so no output created.

Comment: @aljoscha: What are messages, please?

Comment: @Dimtry Bychenko oh sorry. i forgot. The error message is now in my comment.

Comment: @aljoscha: looks like `pdftk.exe` can't process the files: we create an array, say `string[] {"2000019", "2000020"}` and pass it as string `"2000019 2000020"` to `pdftk.exe` which in turn tries to open each item as if it is file -  `"2000019.pdf"` etc. Please, check `pdftk.exe` requirements: should we provide just numbers or complete file names, like `5000023_abc_2000045`?

Comment: @aljoscha: well, as far as I can see, you want to *preserve* file names, but *sort* by first part of the file name. I've edited the answer

Comment: there should be complete filenames.
but sorted by the first name before the _ .

and i need 2 of them. once for the files with "abc" and once for the files with "def".

@Dimtry Bychenko they should then be sorted and merged into one "big" pdf.

the first page 5000023_abc_2000045.pdf. on the next page then 5000023_def_2000045.pdf and so on.

Comment: @Dimtry Bychenko Thank you also for your detailed answer :).